# How to you download .sqlite data from a web app

Tags: javascript, iphone, sqlite, email, cordova

I have created a phone-gap/Icenium web app that allows the user to input a lot of data which is saved to a sqlite table on the phone.

I want the user to be able to export the data from the sqlite on the phone onto a computer for analysis in excel or other spreadsheet editors.

Is there a way to do this with javascript so that it emails/downloads, or would the user need to explore the phone and copy and paste the .sqlite file?

Comment: FYI, this might be of interest to you, regarding remote storage and manipulation: https://parse.com/products/data (I don't work for parse.com in any way)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, the .db file is stored in the Documents folder (you can see this in the Objective C code in the Sqlite plugin) and on Android in /data/data which is not normally available on non rooted Android device.